# Use any type in a function parameter in C++

Tags: c++, pipeline

I am trying to find a way to get this function into a more generic one.

```
  void addStage(Image (f)(Image));
```

The thing i want to get is something that can recieve different types of functions with or without parameters, void or not.

I have tried something like this but of course it is not working.

```
void addStage(auto (f)(auto));
```

For giving more context I will say that this functions are going to be stages from a pipeline.

Comment: What do you plan to do within the function `addStage()` with these different kinds of functions? Are you planning to actually call the function with arguments or what? If you are planning to call the function, how are you planning to do the call with the necessary arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SFINAE:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<T>, void> addStage(T* f) {
    ...
}
```

But, if you don't need any special check (wether `T` is a function or no) you can actually just use a `template` and leave to the compiler all the checks:

```
template<class T>
void addStage(T f) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This accepts any type. If you replace `enable_if` with `enable_if_t`, then it will accept no types (unless you manually specify `T`; the compiler will deduce it as a function *pointer*, not a function). If you replace `T f` with `T *f`, then it will accept functions *only*, not lambdas/functors.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename AnyFunction>
void addStage(AnyFunction f) {
  // implement in header file!
}
```